# What does this error mean? : AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'partition'

Tags: python, error-handling

The code worked fine when i used a string, but then when i used a variable containing the string, it failed.

But the main question is what the error message means. Thx

Comment: It means you are trying to use an attribute `partition` on a Process object that does not exist.  Please show your code.

Comment: Can you provide a code example? Your question is pretty cryptic. How are you using this variable? If it was `attr = 'myattr'`, and you did `Process['attr']` that would break, but `Process[myattr]` should work (assuming `Process` supports string indexing)

Comment: Could you show your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946952/dnf-python3-9-uses-library-from-usr-lib-python3-6 demonstrates this in the context of trying to use a Python 3.9 tool but accidentally using the 3.6 version of the standard library. I guess the code changed between those two versions.

Answer (score 1):

The error means this:

you are using the attribute `partition` on an object of type `Process`, but such `Process` object has no attribute `partition`.

You get the same if you try to invoke partition on a `list`, which doesn't have any attribute named partition:

```
>>> [].partition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'partition'
```